# Encoding for x86 VMCS field "ENCLV-Exiting Bitmap"

Tags: x86, virtual-machine, machine-code, sgx

The Intel® 64 and IA-32 Architectures Software Developer's Manual [Volume 3C: System Programming Guide, Part 3](https://software.intel.com/sites/default/files/managed/7c/f1/326019-sdm-vol-3c.pdf) includes the following description of a control field component of the virtual machine control structure (VMCS):

> #### 24.6.17 ENCLV-Exiting Bitmap
>
> The **ENCLV-exiting bitmap** is a 64-bit field. If the “enable ENCLV exiting” VM-execution control is 1, execution of ENCLV causes a VM exit if the bit in this field corresponding to the value of EAX is 1. If the bit is 0, the instruction executes normally. See Section 25.1.3 for more information.

However, the encoding for this field is not given in Appendix B of [Volume 3D](https://software.intel.com/sites/default/files/managed/7c/f1/332831-sdm-vol-3d.pdf) (where one would expect it to be listed in Table B-4 "Encodings for 64-Bit Control Fields").

Where can one find the encoding for this field, or else how can one report the omission to Intel?

Comment: Yes, you are right it is missing. Funny thing is that "ENCLV-Exiting bitmap" was missing in the version of the manuals I had, yet in the description of `enclv` the pseudo-algorithm given used the "ENCLV-Exiting bitmap". I guess Intel messed up the documentation of this field a bit. IDK where to report this, there are the Intel's forums but I'm afraid your request may be buried under the tons of "can I gamez with this CPU" questions they receive there.

Comment: @MargaretBloom: There are sections of Intel's forums with technical Q&As where reporting ICC compiler bugs or x86 documentation errors will be noticed.

Comment: @PeterCordes Like [this one](https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/virtualization-software-development)? Which one is for the manuals errata?

Comment: Possibly https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/intel-isa-extensions?  https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/software-tuning-performance-optimization-platform-monitoring also gets attention from Intel devs.  IDK exactly; I usually only visit threads there that someone links to, or that I find with google.

Comment: I [posted on Intel's Virtualization Software Development](https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/virtualization-software-development/topic/805555) board but received no answer there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following my report of the omission to Intel, version 072 of the SDM has been updated with the following information in Table B-4:

> ```
> Field Name                  | Index      | Encoding
> ENCLV-exiting bitmap (full) | 000011011B | 00002036H
> ENCLV-exiting bitmap (high) |            | 00002037H
> ```
>
> This field exists only on processors that support the 1-setting of the “enable ENCLV exiting” VM-execution control.